# Iterating through a Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I'm trying to do is go through the Firebase database and see if there's a certain value, if there is then do nothing, if there isn't then add another value to the node.

My Firebase collection looks like this:

```
appname{
Collection{
    key : value
    key : value
    key : value
```

So again, I want to see if an inputed value equals to any value from the collection. If it doesn't then the inputed value should be added into the collection.

EDIT: I have been told to show the code I used that didn't work. I have deleted the code, since I was trying different things. But I'll try to remember how it was. Here:

```
reference.child("strings").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot n : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        if (n == inputedString) {
            break;
        }
    ref.child("strings").setValue(inputedString);
    }
}
```

Again I'm unsure if this is the exact code, but it is similar to it. I've used this answer as help, but couldn't adjust it to my needs: [Firebase/android how get children keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097787/firebase-android-how-get-children-keys-and-values)

Also the problem that I got is that my database was filling infinitely over and over again.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have done it. Hopefully it will be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is effectively listening to the changes that it is also making.  Each call to setValue is going to trigger another callback of the object you passed to `addValueEventListener`.  If you want to iterate each child just once and not listen for updates, then use [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) instead of `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: If I use the same code as above, but instead of .addValueEventListener I use .addListenerForSingleValueEvent it'll work the way it's supposed to? I'm only asking because last time I couldn't stop from overflowing my Firebase database, so I had to make a new one. Don't want the same thing to happen again.

Comment: Yes, and you can always run it slowly in a debugger to watch it work in a way that you manage.

Comment: What I am not getting is this error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot', 'java.lang.String', and it is happening at the if (n == inputedString) { line. What should I do?

Comment: That's because you're supposed to compare strings in java with the equals() method, not ==.

Comment: I have fixed that mistake, just a stupid no-thinking one. I have put your listener instead of mine. It works now in way that it only does it once, but the problem now is that if there isn't the same value, then it simply replaces the previous one, not add.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.  Please post a different question.  We can't go back and forth indefinitely on a variety of problems for a single question.