# How to get child key in Firebase Realtimedatabase

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to paging realtime databse , and my database structure looks like this.

```
{ 
  "dinosaurs":{
    "lambeosaurus": {
      "UID1_1sajdslkjzxdq2311a":{
        "height" : 5.1,
        "length" : 12.5,
        "weight": 3211
      },
       "UID2_2cxzcxczz34zz":{
        "height" : 2.7,
        "length" : 11.5,
        "weight": 5000
      },
    //..

    }
  }
}
```

The key what I want to get is `"UID1_1sa..."`.
I tried with code below.

```
val DBreference = mydb.reference.child("dinosaurs").child("lambeosaurus")
val FirstKey = DBreference.orderByChild("height").limitToFirst(1).get().await().key 
Log.d("FirstKey ","${FirstKey}")
```

but it returns `"lambeosaurus"` not `"UID1_1sa~.."`.
How can I get `"UID1_1sa~.."`?

Thank you.

*Edit

I changed code into

```
    val FirstKey = DBreference.orderByChild("height")
         .limitToFirst(1).get().await().children.first().key
```

It returns `"UID1_1sa..."` as I want.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
val DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
val usersRef: DatabaseReference = rootRef.child("dinosaurs")
val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener() {
    fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            val firstKey: `val` = ds.getKey()
            Log.d("TAG-firstKey ", firstKey)
        }
    }

    fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError?) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed code by using `children`, It actually worked~!